# When should I implement __call__

Tags: python

In python you can make instances callable by implementing the `__call__` method. For example

```
class Blah:
    def __call__(self):
        print "hello"

obj = Blah()
obj()
```

But I can also implement a method of my own, say 'run':

```
class Blah:
    def run(self):
        print "hello"

obj = Blah()
obj.run()
```

When should I implement `__call__`?

Comment: When it makes sense.

Comment: If you're unsure if you need `__call__`, then you don't need `__call__`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is hard to answer. My opinion is that you should never define `__call__` unless your actual goal is to create a function. It's not something you would do after you've already created a traditional object.

In other words, if you're starting out thinking "I'm going to create an object" you should never end up implementing `__call__`. If, on the other hand, you start out thinking "I'm going to create a function... but I wish I could use the object framework to let my function have some state" then you could create the function as an object with state, and define `__call__` to make it act like a function.

I want to include one final bit of advice which was provided by [@Paul Manta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627005/paul-manta) in a comment to the question, where he wrote:

> If you're unsure if you need `__call__`, then you don't need `__call__`

I think that's sound advice.

Comment: +1 - Sometimes closures just become an unspeakable mess, and a callable object is a better approach. But that's about it.